# Multiple ports reported in netstat for one TCP connection

Tags: tcp, port

I run a simple client-server application written in python between two computers that communicate via TCP port 2222 (on both sides). But what I see in netstat report is two other ports, one added at each side. For example what I see at the side of address 149.119.141.140 is as follows:

```
Proto   Local                   Foreign                 State       PID
TCP     149.119.141.140:2222    149.119.140.86:50109    ESTABLISHED 4412
TCP     149.119.141.140:50902   149.119.140.86:2222     ESTABLISHED 4412
```

What can be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

49152 through 65535 ports are for Dynamic/Private

I guess it's related with the fact you're doing it in Private (from virtual machine or Something like that)

generaly when you experience unknown open ports you want to find what process are related to them, by using "netstat -aon" you find out the PID is the same so it seems to be Something that will not bother you

you're not encountering any problems except this, right ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. No there was not a problem in execution. I was just curious to know what is it! BTW, why there should be such a port change by python interpreter? Why it just simply don't use the 2222 ports I specified in the code?

Comment: It is actually using the 2222, you have in addition a range of dynamic port for your private data Stream, that's why you'll have 2 connexions, and so, if you kill the first one, the second will dissapear too, consider them as one